# Send images from dialogflow to webhook

Tags: image, dialogflow-es

my usecase is about sending an image of some disease as attachment and push the same to my python code through webhook. Python code will perform some analytics on the image and send the text response back to dialogflow

I didn't find any datatype to push the image type to python through webhook

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to send images to a webhook